# Netbeans generate hbm.xml files from multiple shcemas of database

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, hibernate-mapping, pojo, hbmxml

i am using netbeans, I am generating POJO and hbm.xml files from a database, but i am able to generate only from one schema only. But I need to create from two different schemas and its tables have cross reference or relationship. How can I do it in Netbeans? or Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
Seems it Netbean's bug, while creating an reverse 
engineering xml file, actually you can not create them from multiple schemas, 
because simply Netbean does not simply generate them. There  are several solutions 
if you dont want to write by hand all codes in reverse engineering file:
1)  First You can generate reverse engineering file from
 Eclipse IDE, then you may copy it and paste in the
 Netbeans reverse engineering file, then it should 
work fine to generate POJO and hbm.xml files;
```